# Overlaping date labels on xaxis in Highstock

Tags: axis, highcharts, overlap, axis-labels

Sometimes edge date labels overlap on my chart:

[image: overlaping date labels]

I was trying to add bigger `tickPixelInterval`, but it doesn't really help me. How can I fix this?

Comment: A picture is nice but show your code...

Comment: did you get the output??

Answer (score 0):

check tickInterval property in highchart api, set some x,y values

```
    >tickInterval : 2,
    labels : { y : -15, rotation: -45, align: 'right' }
```